# New Jirafe Coming Soon! in Spree Admin Overview page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

Is it possible to get the Jirafe pretty circles back in my admin overview page? with any older versions of the https://rubygems.org/gems/spree_dashspree_dash gem. Currently I am seeing only an image saying 
**New Jirafe Coming Soon!**

I am using Spree 1.3 stable version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the Jirafe service is not currently operational.  The Jirafe service in Spree relies upon their third party API, and when that went down it stopped working.

You can read more on the [Jirafe Blog](http://blog.jirafe.com/).  They hope to restore service in the next few months.

In the meantime, you should check out a recent post on the [Spree Blog](http://spreecommerce.com/blog/ecommerce-tracking-in-spree) which outlines how to get better e-commerce tracking with Google Analytics.